# Can't get 5V 3A DC constant

Tags: power-supply, transformer, 5v, linear-regulator, multisim

Here's the circuit I am trying to build.

I want to get 5V 3A DC output but it's giving above 7V and 4A.

I have checked it in the multimeter attached in the diagram.

Can any one explain what's wrong and how to overcome this problem?

Circuit diagram:

[image]

Actually, I have tried the circuit given in the datasheet to get output, but it didn't give the required output so I tried building my own.

[LM2596 datasheet.](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf)

LED load diagram:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to add a link to the datasheet for the regulator you are using.

Comment: Have you tried putting a load on it? That can sometimes solve these issues. I've not used this particular simulation package before though so cannot say for sure

Comment: I was going to try that but thought first to check output in Multimeter of multisim.

Comment: Have a look at page 21 of the datasheet and the minimum load current.

Comment: I think It is saying of using 33uH inductance for 2.5A Max Current.

Comment: Tried Putting it in Simulation and got  6.3-7.5 V 3.6-4.5A DC and it's still fluctuating.

Comment: Have you added a load yet? If so, what value and what happens the output?

Comment: @Transistor    , I have added a LED which runs on Vf=3.45V at 20mA. And got 3.83 V 3.8-4.2A DC output in Multimeter.

Comment: How are you measuring 4.2 A with a 20 mA LED? Are you short-circuiting the output to measure the output current? (That's not how to measure the capability of the device.) Are you wiring an LED directly across the output with no current limiting? (That's not how to use an LED.)

Comment: Wait I will Post the Diagram.@Transistor Please See the above Diagram.

Comment: Your virtual multimeter is shorting the output when set to A. Ammeters go in series- best drill that into your head before you start working with real ammeters or you'll blow some (possibly hard-to-find) fuses, at best.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Ok Wait I will Try This And tell you.

Comment: When I try to Put Multimeter in Series it is Giving Me an Error.

Comment: Would you **please** stop randomly capitalizing words?  [The rules are fairly simple.](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/capitalization-rules/)

Comment: Please, Can you tell me are we here to talk about my typing or my query regarding the circuit?

Comment: @El_Dorado: when someone bothers to give you some feedback you might be wise to pay attention. The effect of your random capitalisation is to give the impression of someone behaving in a strange manner. I noticed it too. This affects both the and credibility of your question and comments. If English is not your native language then you should add that into your user profile so that we can make allowances. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site rules.

Comment: Sorry, Actually I am not very fluent in English and I am in the learning phase. I appreciate his feedback it allows me to improve. I make some typing mistake also. That's why I politely said to him that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with foreign language keyboards trying to type English... but on US/EN keyboards or phones, you have to hit an extra key to capitalize, so it's not done by accident.  English is a hard language - nobody minds plain ESL errors! Everyone is welcome!  Just, that looked more like a "personal style" intentionally done.  Not long ago, it was popular (among children) to capitalize EvErY oThEr LeTtEr... *that* was annoying!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you are making several beginner's mistakes in your understanding and application.

You are using the LM2956 5.0 which is the 5 V version. This will output a regulated 5.0 V subject to meeting certain conditions including the required input voltage and current and having a load drawing between the rated minimum and maximum.

The 3 A maximum output rating of the supply means that it can guarantee 5 V out while delivering 3 A into a load. This means that the minimum load resistance is \$ R = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {5}{3} = 1.7 \ \Omega; \$. **You do not test power supply output current by short-circuiting its output with an ammeter.** To do so risks destroying the meter or, at best, blowing the fuses. In addition the reading is of very little use as that current is delivered when there is no voltage at the output (due to the short-circuit) so you can't power anything with it.

[image]

*Figure 1. LED current versus voltage curves for various colours. Source: [LED IV curves](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/).*

Next. You are showing a dummy load of an LED connected directly across the output. LEDs have a forward voltage, V<sub>f</sub>, usually given when a current of 20 mA is run through the LED. You can see from the graphs that if you connect an LED directly to a 5 V supply that for most of the colours the current drawn is off the scale and, generally, the LED will glow very brightly for a very short time. If your simulator doesn't show that your LED is destroyed then it has a poor LED model. See [LED resistor calculation](http://lednique.com/electrical-theory-basics/ohms-law-and-resistor-calculation/) for more on how to limit the current with a resistor.

How to test your circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGYRUM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Correct PSU monitoring technique.*

The ammeter is always wired **in series with the load**. Voltage measurements are taken **across the load** (or "in parallel" with the load).

Repeat your simulations while increasing the load resistance from 1.7 Ω and see when the regulator starts to misbehave.

Tip: turn off the grid before taking screengrabs. It makes your diagrams easier to read.

Comment: So Sir, in the Place of LED I should Place a 1.7ohm Resistor. and attach multimeter in series with it right? Then I remove Multimeter from there and attach it to parallel to the resistor to check voltage.

Comment: It is not clear from your question or comments if you are doing all of this in simulation or on a real circuit. Yes, connect the appropriate load resistor for the current you want to test. If using a multimeter then select the correct range, plug the leads into the correct sockets and place in circuit as shown in Figure 2.

Comment: Sir, I have Connected it as you told and connected a 12.5-ohm resistor. Placed Ammeter and Voltmeter accordingly

I got In voltmeter 4.989V and in an ammeter 398.988 - 399.05 A fluctuating Current.

And I am doing all this in simulation only. NI Multisim. And I am working right now on it.

Comment: So you are getting 5.0 V and 400 mA (not A as you have written). Calculations give you \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {5}{12.5} = 0.4 \ \text A \$. What is the problem?

Comment: Yeah, there is No problem. I have Replace Resistor with 1.7Ohm resistor and got 4.6V and 2.8A Current. So how can I make it to 5V and 3A?

And Sir, Can you please guide me if I want to Use this Circuit and provide power supply to RPi i should connect it from accross resistor right.

Comment: How can I make it stable? If this is unstable fluctuating source wouldn't it damage the Devices? And in above I have attached a 1.7 Ohm Resistor so that I can Draw 5.1V 3A constant but not getting it

Comment: You will not get exactly 5 V all the time. Switching power supplies  pulse their outputs. The inductor and capacitor filter this and smooth it out quite well but not perfectly. "*And in above I have attached a 1.7 Ohm Resistor so that I can Draw 5.1V 3A constant but not getting it.*" Simulation or real circuit? What *are* you getting?

Comment: I am Using a Simulation and I am getting 4.6V and 2.8A. When I changed Resistor to 1.74 Ohm and that inductance to 22uH I am getting 4.6-4.702V and 2.7 - 2.84 A.

So How can I Achieve 5.1V and 3A

Comment: One other thing Sir, the Current fluctuate very much after some time for few sec. Like from 2.8 to 1.4 then again 2.8

Comment: @El_Dorado as I said in the comments to my answer, the closer you push the device to its maximum, the less reliable it will be. If you are wanting a stable 5V/3A, then get a regulator which can give 5V/5A and you will find that it will be much more stable at 3A. You always want to give yourself some headroom to work with

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. I am looking forward to buying one.

Comment: @El_Dorado it would also be a good idea to accept an answer to this question, as the reasons for your results have been explained and your issue should be resolved. I would suggest accepting this answer over mine as it covers more and includes handy diagrams which mine does not.

Comment: Ok, Sir, I will do it right away.

Answer (score 6):

You are measuring the circuit incorrectly. Your ammeter is shorting the output, this is why you are getting maximum current.

You need a proper load, the LED is not going to work. Use a resistor instead. The datasheet specifies a minimum load current on page 21:

[image]

And seeing as your regulator is the fixed 5V version, you can do Ohms Law calculations to find out the load needed. I would go for around 350 - 400mA. Thus R= 5/0.35 = 14.3, so stick a 15 ohm resistor on your load.

You will then be able to measure the voltage and current, making sure the ammeter is in **series** with the load, and the voltmeter is in **parallel** with the load

Comment: I can't Do that with Multimeter using it like Voltmeter and Ammeter simultaneously. 350mA-400mA (Can't Understand). 

Do you mean I want 3 A output so R= V/I so R= 5/3 = 1.666 ohm?

Comment: You just need to use 2 multimeters then. One set up as an ammeter and one as a voltmeter. If you don't, then you will never be able to read the current correctly. Why can you not understand 350mA-400mA? I do not mean you want a 3A output. You need a 350-400mA output to test that it is working. Change the LED for a resistor. Use Ohm's Law to work out which resistor you need for the load you choose, as long as it is above 310mA which is the minimum needed. It's that simple

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much, Sir. I am  gonna replace LED with R=V/I
So, R = 5/0.4 = 12.5 ohm Resistor.

And Just for clarification with this resistor, we can draw out the maximum current right?

Comment: @El_Dorado no, with this resistor, you will draw 400mA. This is just to make sure that the circuit is behaving.

Comment: yeah, I have Placed a 1.7 Ohm Resistor and changed Inductance to 22uH. But I am not getting 5.1V 3A. I am getting 4.566V 2.7 - 2.8 A. And it is Fluctuating. Sometimes current drops to 1.4 and again come up in milli-sec. Can this damage device?

Comment: @El_Dorado Why are you wanting to get 3A out of it? The closer to the maximum, the less well it will perform. If you are wanting to get 3A constant, I would go for a regulator that can provide 5A

Comment: Ok, If we leave about Current because as you said near to max will not perform well so can you tell me why I am not getting 5.1V? It is needed.

Comment: @El_Dorado You are not getting 5.1V because of the current. You are pushing the device too hard. It is working near its limit, so the voltage is suffering. If you continue to crank up the current, you will notice the voltage start to drop. You are too near the maximum current. You need a regulator that can supply 5A and you will find it to be perfectly stable at 3A. If you want a stable 5V and 3A, then you need to get a 5V/5A regulator. This one will not give you what you need if being used constantly at its maximum current rating

Comment: Ok Boss got Your Point. Thank You So much for your lessons.

Comment: will this one be Alright: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snvs771c/snvs771c.pdf 
or
this One: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2678.pdf

Comment: @El_Dorado simulate them. See what your results are. Use the same load but change the regulator. See what you get. They should be fine. Your first one is an adjustable regulator though, so you will have to calculate the feedback resistors to get 5V. The information for how to do it is written clearly in the datasheet

Comment: @El_Dorado the chip also has "Self-protection features include a two-stage frequency reducing current limit for the output switch and an overtemperature shutdown for complete protection under fault conditions." - I think you are likely running into a thermal issue once you are pushing it to it's limits, see "When load currents higher than 2 A are used, double-sided or multilayer PCB with large copper areas or airflow might be required" - basically while it is rated for 3A, and 3A is achievable, it requires an excellent design that pays attention to ALL the details - oversizing is likely easier

Comment: Ok Sir, got you Point.